# Microsoft Excel 2010 subtraction results in wrong answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

This issue does not care if you format the cells to numeric or not, but formatting them to numeric with 4 or more decimal places helps you see the issue without having to look at the Formula Bar.

Cell A1: Enter 104.19

Cell B1: Enter 98.98

Cell C1: Enter =A1-B1 (it shows 5.2100)

Copy Cell C1 and paste in Cell D1 as a value. It shows 5.2099. <-- WTH?

Same thing happens for:
172.89 - 164.25
167.85 - 159.46

But not for:
63.67 - 60.49
300.98 - 285.93

Additional Step: If you add or multiply Cell D1 by another value, the resulting answer is as if you added or multiplied by 5.2100, not 5.2099.

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78113

Comment: "What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic
or
Why don’t my numbers add up?" http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rounding-error/info